# Git clean single untracked file

Tags: macos, git

I would like only a certain file to be untracked unlike

> git clean

which will remove all untrack files. Thus what is the best way to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Delete it (with `rm` or whatever facility your OS provides for deleting files).

If you want to keep the file, add it to the repo's `.gitignore` file, and Git won't try to track it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

@mlpadi answer is correct as well. In this case though what I was looking for was

> git clean -f {dir_path}

It helped me clean the files from that 1 folder it was complaining about